# How to trigger another button when I press enter key inside my form

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a search bar where if I type anything it processes the answer or the output in another Modal. and then, if I click [search] button, then the modal triggers. Now I want that if I press enter inside the box, it will trigger the button.

```
 <form class="form-inline" >
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-1" onkeyup="SearchFunction()" id="searchinputfeild" 
type="search" placeholder="" aria-label="Search">

        <a class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" id="searchbutton" data-toggle="modal" data- 
target="#resultsModal">Search</a>
      </form>
```

I am very very weak at javascript. please give me suggestions on how can I  make it possible.

Comment: use onSubmit attribute in <form> tag and pass search function into onSubmit

Comment: @RupinderpalThind ummm.. didn't work. can you give the code. because I think I didn't understood very well

Comment: guys Thanks for your suggestions. I just Removed the <form> tag and it made me fully satisfied. thanks for your support and time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hi, you can do this by simple JavaScript Code:**

Your HTML (some changes):

```
<form class="form-inline" >
    <input class="form-control mr-sm-1" id="searchinputfeild" type="search" placeholder="" aria-label="Search">

    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" id="searchbutton" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#resultsModal">Search</button>
</form>
```

> Don't use < a > tag, instead use button.

**Now Finally Place following JavaScript code below in your body (or anywhere):**

```
<script>
 var input = document.getElementById("searchinputfeild");
 input.addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
   event.preventDefault();
   document.getElementById("searchbutton").click();
   }
 });
</script>
```

YOU ARE DONE.

---

It Will work smoothly

---

---

***If you wanna Test, Check it below by running alert test snippet:***

```js
var input = document.getElementById("searchinputfeild");
    input.addEventListener("keyup", function (event) {
     if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      event.preventDefault();
      document.getElementById("searchbutton").click();
      }
   });
```

```html
<form class="form-inline" >
         <input class="form-control mr-sm-1" id="searchinputfeild" type="search" placeholder="" aria-label="Search">

        <button onclick="javascript:alert('Hey Congrats! I am working.')" class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" id="searchbutton" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#resultsModal">Search</button>
</form>
```

Comment: actually, when people type something in my field, it shows an answer in a different Modal. and when I click on the button created with a tag, the modal opens. but when I use button tag, it just submits the answer but I wasn't the button to do data-toggle = modal that it cannot do. so pls give me another suggetion

Comment: yes. tried with < a > and < button >. but it doesn't work. how can I show you a video of this problem?

Comment: guys Thanks for your suggestions. I just Removed the <form> tag and it made me fully satisfied. thanks for your support and time

Comment: Great, But using button was the only solution in form, If you remove form tag, then it will work fine  

Answer (score 1):

```
<form class="form-inline" id="myForm">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-1" id="searchinputfeild" 
type="search" placeholder="" aria-label="Search">

        <a class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" id="searchbutton" data-toggle="modal" data- 
target="#resultsModal">Search</a>
      </form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
    function handleForm(event) { event.preventDefault(); } 
    form.addEventListener('submit', submit);

    function submit(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        console.log('code here')
    }
</script>
```

Comment: guys Thanks for your suggestions. I just Removed the <form> tag and it made me fully satisfied. thanks for your support and time